# Robocopy kept adding backslash in Windows 7 batch script

Tags: batch-file, windows-7, robocopy

I have encounted a extra backslash when trying to copy a single file using in the following batch script on Windows 7 pro:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%" & set "Min=%dt:~10,2%" & set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"


set "DATESTAMP=%YYYY%%MM%%DD%" & set "TIMESTAMP=%HH%%Min%%Sec%"
set "FULLSTAMP=%YYYY%-%MM%-%DD%_%HH%-%Min%-%Sec%"

set BACKUP_FILE=Backup_%FULLSTAMP%
set LOCAL_BACKUP_PATH=c:\Backup\%DATESTAMP%

set REMOTE_BACKUP_PATH=X:\Backup\%DATESTAMP%

set FULL_LOCAL_BACKUP_FILE=%LOCAL_BACKUP_PATH%\%BACKUP_FILE%.zip

set FULL_REMOTE_BACKUP_FILE=%REMOTE_BACKUP_PATH%\%BACKUP_FILE%.zip

if NOT EXIST "C:\Backup\%DATESTAMP%" ( md C:\Backup\%DATESTAMP% )
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z" a -tzip "%LOCAL_BACKUP_PATH%\%BACKUP_FILE%.zip" "C:\Backup\Images.db" "C:\Backup\Images.log" >> C:\Backup\blog.txt 

if NOT EXIST "%REMOTE_BACKUP_PATH%" ( md "%REMOTE_BACKUP_PATH%" )

robocopy %FULL_LOCAL_BACKUP_FILE% %FULL_REMOTE_BACKUP_FILE% /S /E /COPY:DATS /PURGE /MIR /w:1 >> C:\Backup\blog.txt
```

Unfortunately, the robocopy.exe kept appending an extra backslash '\' which resulted in itself not able to find source or destination file as follows:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows                              
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Started : Wed Dec 27 17:36:49 2017

   Source : c:\Backup\20171227\Backup_2017-12-27_17-36-49.zip\
     Dest : X:\Backup\20171227\Backup_2017-12-27_17-36-49.zip\

    Files : *.*

  Options : *.* /S /E /COPY:DATS /PURGE /MIR /R:1000000 /W:1 

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

2017/12/27 17:36:49 ERROR 2 (0x00000002) Accessing Source Directory c:\Backup\20171227\Backup_2017-12-27_17-36-49.zip'`\
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Robocopy appears to try copy source and destination directory as opposed to file.

In short, how to remove the extra backslash that showed up in source and destination? Also, how to make robocopy to only copy file?

I have looked up many similar search results without finding the answer.

Thanks in advance,

George

Comment: I wonder why you have both `/s` and `/e`. They are conflicting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ROBOCOPY** should be used here to copy the single file

```
C:\Backup\20171227\Backup_2017-12-27_17-36-49.zip
```

to directory `X:\Backup\20171227\` with same name.

**ROBOCOPY** appends a backslash to *source* and *destination* because of **ROBOCOPY** is designed for copying multiple files and expects that *source* is a directory and *destination* is also a directory. Run in a command prompt window `robocopy /?` and read at least top of output help.

For some unknown reason there are additionally used here the options `/S` to copy from *source* all subdirectories excluding empty directories and `/E` to copy all subdirectories including also empty subdirectories. Using `/S` **and** `/E` makes never sense and **ROBOCOPY** ignores option `/S` in this conflicting scenario. Also `/PURGE` and `/MIR` do not make sense on copying a single file.

The batch file can be optimized to:

```
@echo off
for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe OS GET LocalDateTime /VALUE') do set "dt=%%I"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%" & set "Min=%dt:~10,2%" & set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"

set "DATESTAMP=%YYYY%%MM%%DD%"
set "FULLSTAMP=%YYYY%-%MM%-%DD%_%HH%-%Min%-%Sec%"

set "BACKUP_FILE=Backup_%FULLSTAMP%.zip"
set "LOCAL_BACKUP_PATH=C:\Backup\%DATESTAMP%"
set "REMOTE_BACKUP_PATH=X:\Backup\%DATESTAMP%"

md "C:\Backup\%DATESTAMP%" 2>nul
"%ProgramFiles%\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -tzip "%LOCAL_BACKUP_PATH%\%BACKUP_FILE%" "C:\Backup\Images.db" "C:\Backup\Images.log" >>C:\Backup\blog.txt

%SystemRoot%\System32\robocopy.exe "%LOCAL_BACKUP_PATH%" "%REMOTE_BACKUP_PATH%" "%BACKUP_FILE%" /COPY:DATS /w:1 >>C:\Backup\blog.txt
```

**ROBOCOPY** is executed by this batch file with a *source* directory, a *destination* directory, the single file to copy and the two additional parameters which make sense on copying a single file.

The destination directory `X:\Backup\20171227\` is automatically created by **ROBOCOPY** and therefore must not be created manually before.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `md /?`
- `robocopy /?`
- `set /?`
- `wmic /?`
- `wmic os /?`
- `wmic os get /?`
- `wmic os get localdatetime /?`

Read also the Microsoft article about [Using Command Redirection Operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your detail advised and I have got it working with the following code:

```
@echo off
for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe OS GET LocalDateTime /VALUE') do set "dt=%%I"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%" & set "Min=%dt:~10,2%" & set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"

set "DATESTAMP=%YYYY%%MM%%DD%"
set "FULLSTAMP=%YYYY%-%MM%-%DD%_%HH%-%Min%-%Sec%"

set "BACKUP_FILE=Backup_%FULLSTAMP%.zip"
set "LOCAL_BACKUP_PATH=C:\Backup\%DATESTAMP%"
set "REMOTE_BACKUP_PATH=X:\Backup\%DATESTAMP%"

md "C:\Backup\%DATESTAMP%" 2>nul
"%ProgramFiles%\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -tzip "%LOCAL_BACKUP_PATH%\%BACKUP_FILE%" "C:\Backup\Images.db" "C:\Backup\Images.log" >> C:\Backup\blog.txt

%SystemRoot%\System32\robocopy.exe "%LOCAL_BACKUP_PATH%" "%REMOTE_BACKUP_PATH%" "%BACKUP_FILE%" /COPY:DATS /w:1 >> C:\Backup\blog.txt
```

### Below is the batch output:

```
ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for windows                              
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Started : Thu Dec 28 11:07:51 2017

   Source : C:\Backup\20171228\
     Dest : X:\Backup\20171228\

    Files : Backup_2017-12-28_11-07-18.zip

  Options : /COPY:DATS /R:1000000 /W:1 

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

      New Dir          1    C:\Backup\20171228\
        New File         375.5 m    Backup_2017-12-28_11-07-18.zip   0.0%...............................................................................................................................100%  
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
               Total    Copied   Skipped  Mismatch    FAILED    Extras
    Dirs :         1         1         0         0         0         0
   Files :         1         1         0         0         0         0
   Bytes :  375.52 m  375.52 m         0         0         0         0
   Times :   0:00:33   0:00:33                       0:00:00   0:00:00
   Speed :            11793404 Bytes/sec.
   Speed :             674.824 MegaBytes/min.
   Ended : Thu Dec 28 11:08:24 2017
```

Cheers,
George